# How to get pygame working in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pygame, pydev

using the pydev plug in to run python 2.7 code in Eclipse. I believe I was somewhat successful in installing pygame into Eclipse as there is no longer an error when I type "import pygame." However, now when I try to reference anything in pygame like "pygame.init()" or "pygame.time.Clock()" Eclipse is giving me the error "Undefined variable from import."

How can I fix this/import pygame correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Installing pygame can be tricky, but if pygame is installed correctly, and PyDev is setup correctly it should all work fine. But pygame must be installed normally, so that other IDEs such as IDLE or the computer shell can access it. Try accessing pygame that way. If they can't, please post the error it gives you.

- If you are on mac, try and install pygame from [these
  instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008679/cant-install-pygame-on-mac/42033710#42033710) , but try and uninstall pygame before installing it again.
- Setup Pydev according to [these instructions.](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) Make sure to click
  next at the bottom of the page for more.