# Getting an error message when trying to download pygame

Tags: python, xcode, pygame

I am trying to download pygame and am getting an error. I am on a mac computer on OS X 10.11.6. I have an updated version of pip and have Xcode already installed.The error comes up when I type in pip3 install pygame. The error is below...

/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c src/scrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/src/scrap.o
    src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include "SDL.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Comment: I just google for "/usr/bin/clang/" and found quite a few results, some of them from other questions here. You may want to start by looking at those answers, compare to the _full_ error message (lines above the one you posted) and once done repost with all the necessary informations - if your problem is not solved yet that is.

Comment: I did try googling the answer and tried everything I could find. Most of them say to download Xcode which I already have. Nothing worked.

Comment: Please re-read my comment more carefully... The error message you get contains much more informations than "command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1". No one can help you without those informations, and if you read them carefully you should be able to find an answer that's more specific than "download xcode" (the SO anwers I'm referring to are indeed more specific cause the OP did post the relevant informations).

Answer (score 1):

Most sites say to run this in terminal: `xcode-select --install` which will install xcode tools.

As for installing pygame with python3 on mac, it can be tricky sometimes, so if running the above in terminal stops that error but brings up another un-xcode-related one, I would suggest going [here](http://pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile#Python3,%20Macs%20and%20Pygame) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008679/cant-install-pygame-on-mac/42033710#42033710) if that link fails.