# Installing Pygame on a MacBook Air M1

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I need Pygame 2 for my project.
I have recently been on a Mac with an M1 processor, but I cannot install Pygame.
I installed Python 3.9 with Homebrew, then SDL and others as recommended.
During installation, version 2.01 of Pygame does not install nor version 2.0.0 but only version 1.9.6.
But this version doesn't work with my project, if I run it it tells me that the pigame.mixer module was not found, moreover the project developer is using Pygame 2 methods.

Here is the result of the installation:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u1qrzt0i
         cwd: /private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/
    Complete output (27 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using Darwin configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/setup.py", line 318, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/buildconfig/config.py", line 221, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 131, in main
        [DependencyProg('SDL', 'SDL_CONFIG', 'sdl2-config', '2.0', ['sdl'])],
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_142bfabb2faa435da22f87624750f4cd/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
        self.ver = config[0].strip()
    IndexError: list index out of range
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/b8/06e02c7cca7aec915839927a9aa19f749ac17a3d2bb2610b945d2de0aa96/pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=8b1e7b63f47aafcdd8849933b206778747ef1802bd3d526aca45ed77141e4001 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pygame-2.0.0.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-x9rp8x3u
         cwd: /private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/
    Complete output (27 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using Darwin configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/setup.py", line 318, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/buildconfig/config.py", line 221, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 131, in main
        [DependencyProg('SDL', 'SDL_CONFIG', 'sdl2-config', '2.0', ['sdl'])],
      File "/private/var/folders/w8/n1kdqpdn6_q0893qnv348s580000gn/T/pip-install-6mir4cqu/pygame_b8f2e42671424b84b18377944477dc5e/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
        self.ver = config[0].strip()
    IndexError: list index out of range
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/0c/d164411381bada8feae57359aa9296defbed3035f4b55bef6a271cb0573c/pygame-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=63b038da116a643046181b02173fd894d87d2f85ecfd6aa7d5ece73c6ef501e9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Possibly you'll find some help here: [Installing PyGame on a Mac OS](https://www.youngwonks.com/blog/How-to-Install-PyGame-on-a-Mac)

Comment: Hello,

Unfortunately this post does not give any useful information to solve my problem.
It just shows how to install Pygame, and I know that.
What I don't know is why when I try to install I get the errors described above.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Neither of the linked questions are about M1 Macs.

Comment: I am not sure if there is M1 specific issues for pygame installation. But I managed to install without issues following this instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208952/1012547 Make sure you are not using python 3.11. I couldn't install without problems with python 3.9./