# Jython install pygame and use it with java in order to connect my controller

Tags: python, java, pygame, controller, jython

I'm working on a java project and I need it to be able to handle the DualShock 4 controller. I saw that with Pygame  and a basic script I can use my controller (all the code is a the end). I can even use my Dualsense controller (PS5 controller) just with this code.

Therefore I wanted to use this very script in my java project using Jython. The issue is that I can't pip install pygame. I have the error

> Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

And I don't know how to handle it.

Furthermore, on this website : https://gatc.ca/2012/02/08/applet-deployment-using-pyj2d/ he create an applet of pygame but I really didn't understand how he managed to do that.

I haven't found a better way to use my controller with java.

here's the python code :

```py
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('game base')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.joystick.init()
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
for joystick in joysticks:
    print(joystick.get_name())

my_square = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 50, 50)
my_square_color = 0
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]
motion = [0, 0]

while True:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors[my_square_color], my_square)
    if abs(motion[0]) < 0.1:
        motion[0] = 0
    if abs(motion[1]) < 0.1:
        motion[1] = 0
    my_square.x += motion[0] * 10
    my_square.y += motion[1] * 10

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.button == 0:
                my_square_color = (my_square_color + 1) % len(colors)
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONUP:
            print(event)
        if event.type == JOYAXISMOTION:
            print(event)
            if event.axis < 2:
                motion[event.axis] = event.value
        if event.type == JOYHATMOTION:
            print(event)
        if event.type == JOYDEVICEADDED:
            joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
            for joystick in joysticks:
                print(joystick.get_name())
        if event.type == JOYDEVICEREMOVED:
            joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

and here's the Java code used to call this python script

```java
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class controller {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        PythonInterpreter pyInterp = new PythonInterpreter() ;
        
        // importer le code python 
        pyInterp.execfile("path2pythonScript/manette.py"); 
        
        
        pyInterp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

If anyone know whether how to install Pygame in my Jython standalone.jar or even a better way to connect my controller I'll take it.

edit : Here's the full output when I try to pip install

```
jython -m pip install pygame==1.9.6                                   

DEPRECATION: pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/sami/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pygame==1.9.6
  Downloading pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sami/jython2.7.3/bin/jython -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-36qzq9/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-36qzq9/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-q8Wv8X
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-36qzq9/pygame/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    /bin/sh: freetype-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: freetype-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: freetype-config: command not found
    WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

I use macOS Ventura
But I don't need to install it on my computer, I need to use it in the Jython package which is independent of the OS used I guess. I can use a Windows laptop If there is solution with it

Edit 2 : SDL is now installed but I still got this error message when I try to install pygame with the same command :

```
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.0.3.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sami/jython2.7.3/bin/jython -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-3gu1yA/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-3gu1yA/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ntnoiG
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-3gu1yA/pygame/
    Complete output (34 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 2.26.1
    FONT    : not found
    ('FONT', 'SDL_ttf.h', 'libSDL2_ttf.so', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    IMAGE   : not found
    ('IMAGE', 'SDL_image.h', 'libSDL2_image.so', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    MIXER   : not found
    ('MIXER', 'SDL_mixer.h', 'libSDL2_mixer.so', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    PNG     : not found
    ('PNG', 'png.h', 'libpng', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    JPEG    : not found
    ('JPEG', 'jpeglib.h', 'libjpeg', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    ('PORTMIDI', 'portmidi.h', 'libportmidi.so', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    PORTTIME: not found
    ('PORTTIME', 'porttime.h', 'libporttime.so', ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/opt/homebrew/lib'])
    FREETYPE: found 24.3.18
    WARNING:root:Some pygame dependencies were not found. Pygame can still compile and install, but games that depend on those missing dependencies will not run. Use -auto to continue building without all dependencies.
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    Missing dependencies
    ----------------------------------------
```

With the -auto flag I got this error :

```
/Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install pygame==1.9.6 -auto

Usage:   
  /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: -a
```

Comment: It looks like Jython only supports Python2, so you could try `jython -m pip install pygame==1.9.6`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full `pip` command output.

Comment: I tired to upgrade pip, download setuptools and still have the same issue

Comment: Can you install a development version of SDL as the log indicates?

Comment: You may also want to consider [Pyj2d](https://github.com/jggatc/pyj2d) but I don't know if it will support your Dual Shock 4. It might be worth testing `python 2.7` and `pygame 1.9.6` to confirm they support your controller before you leap through the hurdles required to build SDL and pygame.

Comment: I don't know how to install the SDL on Jython... in addition, I don't know how to use Pyj2d. I wanted to try to use it but I haven't figured out how to add it in my Jython

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786300/how-to-install-all-sdl-libraries-in-ubuntu-14-04) might help you get SDL dev installed, so you can build pygame. You could edit your question with your operating system details to get more targeted info. Note that you'll want to  install SDL version 1.

Comment: The issue is that SDL dev is installed on my system, but not on the Jython folder I can't sudo apt-get install in Jython. Is there a way to do it manually ?

Comment: The pygame installer is trying to execute the `sdl-config`, but it can't find it. The [SDL MacOS doc](https://github.com/bminor/SDL/blob/master/docs/README-macosx.md) might help you.

Comment: I installed SDL but now it seams that pygames installer is wrong any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try adding the `-auto` flag to try to continue without dependencies? The [pygame compilation page for MacOS](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile) shows how to install dependencies using `brew`. That page also links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033710/2280890) which might help you.

Comment: The -auto flag isn't recognized by jython. I want to emphasize that I can install pygame on my computer, without all of theses manipulation. I need to run a special version of pip and python which is not influenced by brew, and others installation for Jython. It's located at /Users//jython2.7.3/bin/jython . I tried everything you told me but I don't understand why it still doesn't work since I got It installed on my version of python. The jython pip should be able to install the pygame. I tried other lib such as matplotlib, bs4 and more but I have the same issue...

Comment: Where are you including the `-auto` argument? I think it should be at the end: `jython -m pip install pygame==1.9.6 -auto`, but I can't test it.